# Loop - How to add onto a variable each loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add onto a variable each time a loop is ran. In this loop I want each loop to add `hey` to `hey`. So that `hey` is added 13 times. My loops is only adding it once which is confusing me. I am only trying to get this to show up in the console at the moment. Thank you!

```js
const repeatString = function() {

    let test = 'hey';
    let add = 'hey';

    for (let i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        return test += add;
    }
}

console.log(repeatString());
```

Comment: shorter? `"hey".repeat(13)`

Answer (score 3):

You are returning from the function in the first iteration. You should return from outside of the loop (after the completion of the loop):

```js
const repeatString = function() {

    let test = 'hey';
    let add = 'hey';

    for (let i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        test += add;
    }
    return test;
}

console.log(repeatString());
```